# Unable to fetch inapp products for Xamarin Android using Plugin.InAppBilling package

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm having trouble retrieving my in-app products for my Android Xamarin app. I'm using the `Plugin.InAppBilling` nuget package (version 4.0.1-beta) to implement the billing functionality. To begin, I following the documentation which states the following:

```
Android Testing:
- You MUST use a physical device. Emulators do not work.
- Ensure you have app in Alpha/Beta with the NuGet installed. This will add “com.android.vending.BILLING” permission for you
- Create an IAB product, make sure it is published and active
- Add a test account to the app, ensure it is the main account on device, and that account is opted-in as tester
- Validated your version code and number in your development environment match what is in the Play store.
- You MUST sign the APK even in debug mode.
```

### Therefore I have the following specified in my Android csproj:

[image]

### This is my aab package in the Play Console in Internal Testing with 2 testers:

[image]

[image]

### Here are the testers also added as Licensed Testers:

[image]

### However, using the following code doesn't return any products from the call to `GetProductInfoAsync`:

```
private partial async Task FetchProductDetails(bool isAdsDisabled)
{
    var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;

    try
    {
        //You must connect
        var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync();

        if (!connected)
        {
            //Couldn't connect
            return;
        }

        var products = await billing.GetProductInfoAsync(ItemType.InAppPurchase, productIds);
        
        .
        .
        .
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }
    finally
    {
        await billing.DisconnectAsync();
    }
}
```

Anyone know if I missed a step? Something missing?

Comment: Did you try to use  `var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync(ItemType.InAppPurchase);` ?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't exist anymore. I'm on the beta version which contains many changes needed for android.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation, you need an app in Alpha/Beta. Internal testing will not work.

Comment: This was the fix. I pushed my app to Closed Testing (Alpha) and I received my in-app products.

Answer (score 0):

License Response. You have Licensed. I've always used RESPOND_NORMALLY.

I'm not using the plug in as I wrote my own using xamarin.android.google.billingclient\3.0.0. All working here.

Well, what happens when you debug GetProductInfoAsync?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Didn't work, I still get nothing.